# Where to store a queryable user specific log in a domain?

Tags: c#, sqlite, logging, active-directory

I have a app that is running on a Remote Desktop Session Host Server that is tracking user logon/logoff/idle times, however I do not know where a good place to store the data I am gathering.

The user turnover rate is fairly high, a user account will only exist for 1-4 months and will have at most about 3KB of XML formatted logs associated with it.

The data needs to be retrievable from other users (specifically a service that other users query) so I think storing it in the users AppData folder is out of the question.

I was thinking storing a XML log in a Active Directory Attribute but I do not know if Active Directory is really designed to store text blobs in the 3KB range.

My last thought was using something like a SQLite database. However with the high user turnover rate I was hoping to use something that was stored per user. That way when the user is deleted the records are deleted with the user and I don't need to worry about keeping a database in sync if a user is deleted via methods outside of the management software I have set up.

What is the best option to log records in this situation?

Comment: a designated folder per user?

Comment: Just a thought. Does the data have historical value? For example you many not delete it when the user account no longer exists and you can then perform some comparative analyses on it.

Comment: Once the account has been deleted the login history has no value. This is only to track how often and how long users are connecting to the RDSH server. This is used for clients to review their data before we go live and move our software from our "preview" servers to their servers and we need to track how often and how long they are looking over their data. Once they are installed the account is deleted and we don't need the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a log-folder containing sub-folders per user.

Running a (scheduled) powershell script to cleanup after deleting the account, or archiving if historical info suddenly gets a value.

The data is then at a specified location, easy locatable and accessible for (only) the user without polluting the AD.